# What is the quota limit for calling the Google Contacts v3 API

Tags: google-api

I ask ahain the same question asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702489

This question was closed with the comment "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened"

So my question is not ambiguous at all, but very clear : As we can find quota limits for all Google API, I cannot find this answer for Contacts API V3 (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

Example of quota limits on Analytics : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#general_api

Best regards

Comment: Surely, if your question has been closed, you should edit the original question in order to have it reopened, rather than keep asking the same question.

The *stupid* approach (stupid because there must be a better way of getting results than T&E) : Keep sending and counting requests until Google's API returns a result informing you that the limit has been reached.

Comment: this is really a helpfull answer...

Answer (score 4):

As of now the stated quota for the Contacts API v3 is 20,000,000 requests per day for free.  This is determined from my developer console where I have a project defined that uses the Contacts API, and this is what they show under: *myproject* / APIs & auth / APIs / Contact API / Quota.

I actually don't think they are even counting requests though, as mine show all 0 (Usage tab), even though I know it isn't 0.  Other projects that use other APIs like the Calendar do correctly count/show requests, but Google seems to currently be giving as many requests for Contacts API as you want.

Comment: You can access the developer console at this URL: https://console.developers.google.com/. My limit is the same.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/UQGLFFPwyFo

According to this there is no fee and the quota is 10k / day per user.